Create a Windows shortcut without New > Shortcut
Any web search to create a Windows shortcut on the Desktop advises:

Right-click the Desktop
Select New > Shortcut

The New > Shortcut option is not available on my computer. Is there another way to create a generic shortcut on Windows 10/11?
Background: Unsure why I don't have the Shortcut option. This menu was edited some time ago, though I cannot recall the exact details. All I see now are Folder and Text Document (which are all the options I need 99% of the time).

try this; Drug and drop any program from start menu > right click > properties  edit as you want

It works with non-MS store apps only

@ZoomMan2: So simple! Just copy any existing shortcut and edit the details. That works for me.

*Drag
not drug

Open file explorer.  Copy application file.  Find location on desktop.  Right click, choose "paste shortcut".

Right click > Send to > Desktop (Create Shortcut) on whatever you want the shortcut to, app, file, folder. anything really.

Easiest ways to do this are:

Drag and drop any program from the start menu > right click > properties and edit the details. (Does not work with MS Store
apps.)

Copy any existing shortcut and edit the details.



Perfect! This should work with any existing shortcut. You can also create a temporary shortcut by right-clicking any program, select Create shortcut, then edit details.

Start dragging some file, preferably the file you want to make a shortcut to. Before you release the mouse, hold down the ALT key. You should see the tooltip change to "Create link in <destination name>". Once you release the mouse, a shortcut to the file is made where you dropped it. You can then proceed to edit the shortcut, if required.

Been using Windows for 20+ years and never knew about ALT (create shortcut) and CTRL (copy instead of move) as you drag a file. Just tested and this also works in Windows XP (although only a little icon, rather than text, in the tooltip). Awesome, thanks!

Also worth noting that SHIFT forces a move (a "shift") rather than a copy. By default, Explorer will "move" when dragging and dropping a file between locations on the same drive, but "copy" when dragging and dropping between different drives. Holding Shift changes the latter case to a "move".

Another useful tip: use the right mouse button when clicking and dragging a file or folder (no modifier keys required). On releasing the button you'll get a menu with options of what you'd like to do with the file you've dragged to that location: either copy, move or create shortcut(s) to that location. EDIT: I see that's been suggested in an answer below.

You can drag and drop any icon/program with the right mouse button instead of the left.
This provides a context menu on drop which allows to create a shortcut.

It may not be the same kind of shortcut, but you can create a symbolic link with  mklink on the command line.
mklink shortcut-filename target-filename


With powershell, you can create a lnk shortcut (like the new -> shortcut context menu action would produce):
$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('shortcut-filename.lnk');$s.TargetPath='target-filename';$s.Save()


If you wish to restore the usual behavior and add shortcut back to the right-click > new menu it is defined by the following registry values:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{E357FCCD-A995-4576-B01F-234630154E96}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

This code block can be copy-pasted into a text editor like notepad, saved as a .reg file  and imported into your registry.

For web shortcuts you can use the following python function, which essentially just writes a special text file:
import os

def make_shortcut(name, path, target):

    shortcut_name = "".join(c for c in name if (c.isalnum() or c in "._- "))
    shortcut_path = os.path.join(path, shortcut_name + '.url')
    
    lines = '\r\n'.join([
        '[InternetShortcut]',
        'URL=%s' % target,
        'IconFile="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"',
        'IconIndex=0',
        ''
    ])

    with open(shortcut_path, mode='w') as shortcut:
        shortcut.write(lines)

I expect it is also possible to create other types of shortcuts via a similar method but I don't know the syntax.

Microsoft maintains a document describing the complete structure of the binary .LNK format: PDF or HTML
